# How to append or replace document field in elastic search php?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to write update query which replace or append field content

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'products',
    'type' => 'product',
    'id' => '57b31c5c04736da90a91bc2b',
   'body' => [
        'script' => 'ctx._source.product_content_changes = ctx._source.product_content)',

    ]
];

$result =$client->update($params);
```

My requirement is to replace or append content in product_content field.
For example 
product_content => This Is Test Text i want to replace **Test** to **Changed** so new field will contain this text **This Is Changed Text**.

In mysql this query will be something like this

```
update products set product_content_changes = replace(product_content,'Test','Changed') where id="57b31c5c04736da90a91bc2b";
```

Thanks